# How can I repair this drywall joint before taping the seam?

Tags: drywall, walls, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

Long story short, a contractor did a poor job of taping all the seems on my living room ceiling. They used mesh tape and every seem cracked within the first 6 months. I've removed the mesh tape and plan to fill the gap and retape with paper tape, but some of the seems tore the drywall paper.

My question is, how to best repair this seem without sacrificing even more of the strength that is missing from the broken drywall paper? Bonus question, am I overthinking this and this isn't that big a deal in the end?

[image: Torn up drywall paper]

Comment: Yes, you're overthinking this.  Layer of mud, embed the paper tape, then another lay of mud, all at the same time (don't want the first layer of mud to dry).

Comment: If you pulled off the paper, the taping was not that bad.  As others said , mud...tape...mud.  It is not unusual for new construction to get cracks from materials drying and settling.  Those cracks could have been filled with caulk and touched up.  You did more damage removing the tape.

Comment: You're supposed to use setting type mud with mesh tape. That's my first guess why it failed. If surface paper has delaminated from the paper under it, then bubbles tend to form there. Exposed brown paper tends to bubble. I always just use oil based Kilz to seal it up and prevent the bubbles (I prefer Kilz to that Gardz stuff that is supposed to be specifically designed for your use case). There are a bunch of products that work. Basically any non-water based paint or primer, I suspect.

Comment: @popham Not true. Draw tite is water based and made specifically for that purpose and does an amazing job.

Comment: Gap is a little big; needs a backfill first. Which you need to do and then let it set. If you try to do it all at once (when there is a substantial gap) *that's* how you get bubbles even with full contact.

Comment: @Mazura, you reminded me that ASTM C840 calls for filling with setting type mud for gaps wider than 1/8" like the OP's.

Comment: Hey, thank you everyone for the info. I agree @RMDman, I did do some damage in a couple spots but the majority of the mesh tape came off without any damage to the paper.

Comment: Thank you @SteveSh for easing my mind a bit.

Comment: Most of all thanks @popham for the oil based kilz recommendation. I had forgotten that was a good solution to stop bubbling from happening. I dont see how to mark it as the answer, but if I could it would be what popham said. Thanks again all!